# the updateOne function is not updating the document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am attempting to update a document in MongoDB using the updateOne function. I am not receiving any errors and the program is using the correct id, but the document is not being updated. If anyone can show me where I am going wrong it would be much appreciated.

The event schema code is:

And the req.body is:

Comment: Can you Event schema  and req.body to the question?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Could you please explain it.

Comment: Just add your Event schema code,  and the req.body by console.log(req.body) to the question.

Comment: So when I update the information it changes when I console.log(req.body), but it does not change when I attempt to display the new information.

Comment: You have in schema userEmail required field, but in your body there is no userEmail.

Comment: I added userEmail to my body but it still produces the same result. (I have updated the question)

Comment: Can you change this `Event.updateOne( { "_id" : ObjectId(id)}` part with `Event.findByIdAndUpdate(id`

Comment: Also in your request.body there is still no userEmail!!

Comment: I made those changes, yet I am still getting the same result.

Comment: I added this inside of my body: updatedUserEmail : req.body.userEmail

Comment: Where is userEmail here in req.body? ``{ eventName: 'test123', eventLength: 'multiDay', startDate: 'April 6th, 2020', endDate: 'April 1st, 2020', venueName: 'Test place', venueCity: 'Toronto', venueState: 'ON', photographerCB: 'yes', photographyBudget: '1000', videographerCB: 'yes', videographyBudget: '1000', entertainmentCB: 'Yes', entertainmentBudget: '1000' }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210951/discussion-between-vraj-patel-and-suleymansah).

Comment: I am not changing the user's email with this update function.

Comment: ok, can you check the answer?

Comment: userEmail is not a part of req.body, it is a part of req.user

Comment: Ok, got it. Check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields in the information object must match the field names in the Event schema:

so you need to change like this:

```js
  const information = {
    eventName: req.body.eventName,
    eventLength: req.body.eventLength,
    startDate: req.body.startDate,
    endDate: req.body.endDate,
    venueName: req.body.venueName,
    venueCity: req.body.venueCity,
    venueState: req.body.venueState,
    photographerCB: req.body.photographerCB,
    photographyBudget: req.body.photographyBudget,
    videographerCB: req.body.videographerCB,
    videographyBudget: req.body.videographyBudget,
    entertainmentCB: req.body.entertainmentCB,
    entertainmentBudget: req.body.entertainmentBudget,
  };
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @VrajPatel you are welcolme. I appreciate if you can also upvote. By the way there are no CB fields in your schema, but you send photographerCB, videographerCB, entertainmentCB fields.

Comment: I know. CB represents wether a switch is flipped or not.